# How to make a todo entry show multiple states

Tags: org-mode

I would like to make my todo entries show a state for each sequence.

That is, given this configuration

```
(setq org-todo-keywords
  '((sequence "TODO(t)" "|" "DONE(d)")
    (sequence "REPORT(r)" "BUG(b)" "KNOWNCAUSE(k)" "|" "FIXED(f)")))
```

I can create an entry like these ones:

```
* TODO BUG My entry
* TODO REPORT Second entry
* DONE FIXED A third one
```

Is there a way to do it? If not, what is another way to achieve the same result?

Comment: [Org mode syntax](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-syntax.html#Headings) allows for a single TODO keyword only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that: [Org mode syntax](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-syntax.html#Headings) allows for a single TODO keyword only.

If you try to add a second one, perhaps like this:

```org
#+TODO: TODO DELEGATED WAITING | COMPLETED

* DELEGATED TODO foo
  ...
```

you will see from the fontification that `TODO` is not recognized as a TODO keyword in that position.

In fact, if you ask the parser to parse this (place the cursor at the asterisk and say `M-: (org-element-at-point)`), you'll get the following (partial) parse tree:

```el
(headline
 (:raw-value "TODO foo" 
  :begin 45 :end 1065 
  :pre-blank 1 
  :contents-begin 67   :contents-end 1065 
  :robust-begin 69 :robust-end 1063 
  :level 1 
  :priority nil 
  :tags nil 
  :todo-keyword
             #("DELEGATED" 0 9
               (face
                (org-todo org-level-1)
                org-todo-head "TODO" fontified t))
  :todo-type todo 
  :post-blank 0 
  :footnote-section-p nil 
  :archivedp nil :commentedp nil :post-affiliated 45 
  :title "TODO foo" :mode nil :granularity element 
  :parent
             (org-data
              ...)))
```

So the TODO keyword is `DELEGATED` and the title is `TODO foo`.